# PHPmailer AddEmbeddedImage failed to embed Image

Tags: php, phpmailer

I tried two different email client tried google & stackoverflow answered. But failed to solve the issue. I also tested the local image path, it is perfectly ok.

Here is the coding part:

```
  $mail->addEmbeddedImage('../img/abc-company-
   logo.png','logo','abc-company-logo.png');
```

Body Part:

```
$mail->Body    = "<div id='container' style='height:auto;font-
   family:Helvetica;border: 1px solid #CCC;'>
 <div id='header' style='margin: 0 auto; 
  background-color:#0958C3; color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;text-align: center;
display:block;
 '>
<img src='cid:logo' alt='Picture Description'/> <br>
<strong>Heading</strong> 
 </div>
</div>";
```

Comment: What does the call to `addEmbeddedImage` return? Using a relative path like that is very error-prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that `PHPMailer` embeds inline images relative to
where the script is called from, instead of relative to the document
called in.

This means by passing `../img/abc-company-logo.png` to the `addEmbeddedImage()` will search for such path relative to the **actual PHPMailer class file location**.

You should change the path to an absolute file path.
See `__DIR__`, `__FILE__` examples here http://php.net/manual/fa/language.constants.predefined.php

For Example:

```
$mail->addEmbeddedImage(dirname(__DIR__) . '/img/abc-company-logo.png','logo','abc-company-logo.png');
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, let me try and get back to you

Comment: I've added more precise example code, but you should debug and make sure you pass the correct absolute file path to the `addEmbeddedImage` method.

Comment: I am confuse at some point, what should be the directory name? this particular php file is in "includes" folder and image are in "img" folder. I tried includes(_DIR_).rest of the code but it shows undefine function includes

Comment: PHPMailer class files are also in "includes" folder

Comment: `includes(__DIR__)` produces error undefine function includes

Comment: Why are you using `includes(__DIR__)` ? Replace the whole line with `$mail->addEmbeddedImage(dirname(__DIR__) . '/img/abc-company-logo.png','logo','abc-company-logo.png');`

Comment: I am not gins, I shared the part code of it in the comment section, of course, I used the full line of code on php file.

Comment: Ok, but this `error undefine function includes` means you are calling `includes` function?!

Comment: Here is the full line of code : `$mail->addEmbeddedImage(includes(__DIR__).'/img/abc-company-logo.png','logo','abc-company-logo.png');` The folder name is "includes" so I use includes, but php is thinking something else

Comment: This is not a valid PHP syntax, please replace the whole line with: `$mail->addEmbeddedImage(dirname(__DIR__) . '/img/abc-company-logo.png','logo','abc-company-logo.png');`

Comment: `dirname()` is actually a function see http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: `dirname()` will read the directory name of your current directory, and will actually return the parent directory name, the one you want from to point to your images directory.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, let me try

Comment: Please debug the first argument and make sure that you are passing the right full file path to the image file.

Comment: Debugging is done its correctly showing right path. No problem over there. Then not sure why still with phpmailer its not working. Does moving the picture into the "includes" folder can solve the problem temporarily?

Comment: This the link which I am getting `C:\xampp\htdocs\clientphp/img/abc-company-logo.png` picture is also openning with this link. PHP Code for this is `echo dirname(__DIR__).'/img/abc-company-logo.png';`

Comment: After lots of trial and error. This worked simply.
 `$mail->addEmbeddedImage('img/abc-company-
     logo.png','logo');`
Removed the two dots.